# Unable to use variables in alias in cshell

Tags: command-line, environment-variables, alias, csh, tcsh

This is a sample straight forward program. I am using C-shell and want a solution for this environment itself. Following this code sample:

```
set FILENAME = "\!:2"

alias jo 'echo this is my \!:1 file and its name is $FILENAME'
```

on command line when I give the following:

```
jo first sample.txt
```

I should get the output as

```
this is my first file and its name is sample.txt
```

instead I get

```
this is my first file and its name is !:2
```

The problem here is the symbol \ totally gets eliminated, I don't know how. That is needed if I want it to take the argument. Can anyone help out with this?

Comment: If I understood correctly your question, you want to use a variable as part of the alias command, expanding it at runtime with its value. By the way: welcome to AskUbuntu!

Comment: yes its correct. thankfully for the solution. unfortunately i have to work with csh so its kinda difficult to find solutions for such minor things and glad to be here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve the desired result, you should wrap the alias' second argument with double quotes, so the variable filename gets interpreted correctly:

```
set FILENAME = "\!:2"
alias jo "echo this is my \!:1 file and its name is $FILENAME"
```

---

**Test case:**

```
% jo first sample.txt
this is my first file and its name is sample.txt
```

Comment: If this asnwer solved your question, please mark It as accepted by clicking the tick mark on the left and (optionally) upvote it with the up-pointing arrow. If you prefer to wait for another answer, feel free to wait more time. If you need any additional explaination or clarification, don't hesitate to comment here.